# Grails app on Tomcat forgets timezone a few days after deployment

Tags: grails, tomcat8

I am running a large Grails app on a CentOS server.

The server is set to EST (GMT - 5).

When I deploy the app (as a war file), the app's date and time will be correct for a few days, and then suddenly the app becomes confused and thinks it is in GMT, not EST.

This causes dates on domain objects to be incorrect, and also causes Quartz jobs to run at the wrong time. For example:

- We have a job that runs daily at 6:15AM EST and sends out reports by
  email. This happens at the correct time for a few days after
  deployment, and then suddenly the daily job starts running at 1:15AM
  instead.
- Date fields displayed with g:formatDate will show GMT instead
  of EST but the hours / minutes / seconds in the date itself don't
  change, so every time the record is saved the date ends up being
  pushed forward five hours.

Currently running Grails version 2.4.4, Apache Tomcat/8.0.15, OpenJDK 1.8.0, but we experienced the same behavior with various 2.3.x versions of grails, Tomcat 7, and Java 7.

I'm still not sure if this is a Grails problem, or a Tomcat problem. Any ideas how to troubleshoot it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you rule out, that something is messing with "global" state in your code (e.g. `TimeZone.setDefault()`)?

Comment: That was the problem! There was an errant TimeZone.setDefault() in a little-used area of the application. 

Please change your comment to an answer and I'll close this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was the use of `TimeZone.setDefault()` somewhere in the code.

Modifying global state like this anywhere in an application is extremely dangerous!

Even if used in code, that is at first glance "protected" by something like this `old = current(); set(new); dostuff(); set(old)`, is likely to break (but much harder to catch) as it does the change for a short time period and errors around it get more obscure. Exceptions will do the rest...